# Date comparison fails d1.compareTo(d2)

Tags: codenameone

Date comparison for sorting doesn't work. Please advise.

My code:

```
public class ListMapComparator implements Comparator {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        try {
            Map<String, String> test1 = (Map<String, String>) obj1;
            Map<String, String> test2 = (Map<String, String>) obj2;
            String string1 = test1.get("formattedDate");
            String string2 = test2.get("formattedDate");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date d1 = sdf.parse(string1);
            Date d2 = sdf.parse(string2);
            return d1.compareTo(d2);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(ListMapComparator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Error:

> error: cannot find symbol
> return d1.compareTo(d2);
> symbol:   method compareTo(Date)
> location: variable d1 of type Date
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Answer (score 3):

The `Date` class in Codename One isn't comparable so calling `compareTo` will fail. You can however do roughly the same thing by changing the last line to:

```
return (int)(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());
```

Or the other way around to sort in the reverse order.

Comment: This is a nice solution, however casting it to `int` didn't work accurately in my case. This example (from earliest date to the latest) was more accurate: 
`return Long.compare(date1.getTime(), date2.getTime());`